# Why is the value of hashmap not getting updated with getOrDefault method?

Tags: java

```
List<String> list = hmap.getOrDefault(key,new ArrayList<String>());
list.add(s);
hmap.put(key,list);
```

Why do I need to use hmap.put method again?

My understanding is this.

Assume there is no existing key value pair. So, with

```
List<String> list = hmap.getOrDefault(key,new ArrayList<String>());
```

I am mapping key with a new instance of the ArrayList.

If I then add a string to the same instance then the hashmap also should get updated automatically right? key => List Object. If I add to the list object then the object reference should not change right?

Why do I need to again use the put method and do this?

```
hmap.put(key,list);
```

Comment: This assumption is wrong : *I am mapping key with a new instance of the ArrayList.*.

Comment: I think the name of the method `getOrDefault` is pretty clear about not `put`ting anything anywhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`getOrDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-):

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or `defaultValue` if this map contains no mapping for the key.

It says nothing about inserting the default value if the key is not found.

So if the key is not found, it does return that new list and you add an element to it, but you also need to `put()` that new list into the map. If the key was found, then put'ing it again doesn't hurt (except for performance).

However, the correct way to do this is to use [`computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-), for 2 reasons:

- It will put the new list for you.
- If the key exists, it will not create an list just to throw it away again.

```
hmap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>())
    .add(s);
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `HashMap.computeIfAbsent`. `getOrDefault` just gets the value if it exists, otherwise it returns the default, without adding it.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function- and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-

Answer (score 3):

To make it in one shot you have to use [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) :

```
hmap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(s);
```